# Brezis section 7.2, theorem 7.3

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

This is from Brezis' Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces, and PDEs book. Theorem 7.3 reads:

Let $E$ be a Banach space, $F: E \rightarrow E$ a Lipschitz map. If $u_0 \in E$ then there exists a unique solution $u \in C^1([0,\infty); E)$ of the problem $$\begin{cases} \frac{du}{dt}=Fu(t) &\mbox{on } [0, \infty), \\ u(0) = u_0. & \\ \end{cases}$$

The proof defines a Banach space: let $k > 0$, and set
$$ X = \{u \in C([0, \infty); E) \mid \sup_{t \geq 0} e^{-kt} \lVert u(t) \rVert < \infty\}. $$
Then if $u \in X$, we claim
$$ (\Phi u)(t) = u_0 + \int_0^t F(u(s))ds $$
is also an element of $X$.

My question is why? If $F = \mbox{id}_E$ and $u(t) = f(t)u_0$ with $\lVert u_0 \rVert = 1$ and $f(t) \in \mathbb R_{>0}$, then membership $u \in X$ says $\sup_{t \geq 0} e^{-kt}f(t) < \infty$ while membership $\Phi u \in X$ says $\sup_{t \geq 0} e^{-kt}(1 + \int_0^t f(s)ds) < \infty$. It seems to me that although $e^{-kt}f(t)$ might be bounded, $e^{-kt}\int_0^t f(s)ds$ might not, since there are functions whose integral grows quicker than itself. On the other hand, I can somewhat reason that this growth is "polynomial", in the sense $\int_0^t sds = \frac{t^2}{2}$ grows faster than $t$ but polynomially so, and therefore continues to be controlled by $e^{-kt}$.

Is there any direct proof or intuition for why $u \in X$ implies $\Phi u \in X$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ease notation a little, I'll assume $u_0=0$ and $F(0)=0$.

Let $C=\sup_{s\geq 0}e^{-ks}\|u(s)\|$ and $L$ the Lipschitz constant of $F$. Then
$$
\left\lVert\int_0^t F(u(s))\,ds\right\rVert\leq \int_0^t \|F(u(s))\|\,ds\leq \int_0^t L\|u(s)\|\,ds\leq CL \int_0^t e^{ks}\,ds\leq \frac{CL}{k}e^{kt},
$$
that is,
$$
\sup_{t\geq 0}e^{-kt}\|(\Phi u)(t)\|\leq \frac{CL}{k}.
$$

Comment: A bit embarrassed I didn't see I could bound the integral in that way, but thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @MaoWao. Nice answer ! Just correct  the typo $e^{-kt}$ should be $e^{-ks}$ in the line where you define $C$.

Comment: @Medo Thanks, fixed.